# jfrog go commands with parameters

Tags: go, artifactory, jfrog-cli, go-modules

[Documentation](https://jfrog.com/blog/goproxy-artifactory-go-registries/) suggests to build a project with `jfrog rt go build --no-registry`. We are using go modules and the command fails on recognising current module - `can't load package: package  unknown import path cannot find module providing package`, same as `go build` does.

`go build ./...` does work though but I can't do `jfrog rt go build ./.. --no-registry`. Does `jfrog rt go build --no-registry` do anything else apart from calling `go build` anyway? Is there a way to pass the parameters?

Comment: Try running `jfrog rt go "build ./..." --no-registry` (with build and `./...`) in quotes. That seems to work on my machine (after removing my local package cache I can see the modules being downloaded from GitHub)

Comment: Ha! That worked, thanks. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run `jfrog rt go "build ./..." --no-registry` (with `build` and `./...`) in quotes. That seems to work on my machine (after removing my local package cache I can see the modules being downloaded from GitHub).

Comment: strange though that you can't do `jfrog rt go "build ./..."`

Comment: I mean `jfrog rt go "build ./..." --no-registry` works for me but `jfrog rt go "build ./..."` doesn't